# What is the reason for the error message missing statement body in do loop (MissingLoopStatement)?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://web.dev/codelab-serve-images-webp/) and encountered this error:

```
PS C:\_o\webp\bin> C:\_o\webp\bin\cwebp.exe
Usage:

    cwebp [options] -q quality input.png -o output.webp

where quality is between 0 (poor) to 100 (very good).
Typical value is around 80.

Try -longhelp for an exhaustive list of advanced options.
PS C:\_o\webp\bin> `for file in images/*; do C:\_o\webp\bin\cwebp.exe -q 50 "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"; done`
At line:1 char:26
+ `for file in images/*; do C:\_o\webp\bin\cwebp.exe -q 50 "$file" -o " ...
+                          ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingLoopStatement
```

Command:

```
`for file in images/*; do cwebp -q 50 "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"; done`
```

Comment: You'e running PowerShell, whereas the command you're trying to execute is for a POSIX-compatible shell such as Bash.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in Windows 11

1. Enable Virtualization in your BIOS;
2. In Windows Settings > Privacy & security > For developers, toggle the Developer Mode;
3. Go to Windows Settings > Apps > Optional features > More Windows features and check the "Virtual Machine Platform" and "Windows Subsystem for Linux" checkboxes (You may need to restart your computer.);
4. Open Microsoft Store and search & install Ubuntu (You can choose your preferred distro. You may need to restart your computer.);
5. You should be able to complete the Ubuntu installation. If you encounter an error, check this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual.

### Running the script/command

1. Open Ubuntu (You can find it in Start menu > All apps.);
2. Type your script/command.

---

### How to batch convert images to WebP in Windows?

#### Option 1: using WSL

**Prerequisite:** You must have WSL installed. Instructions above.

1. For us to easily access the images and directory, create a folder in Drive C called "convert" and move the unoptimized images in this folder;
2. Open Ubuntu (You can find it in Start menu > All apps.);
3. Go to the root directory by typing `cd /`;
4. Mount your File System by typing `cd mnt`;
5. Access the "convert" folder by typing `cd c/convert`;
6. Run the following script (don't forget the backticks):

```
`for file in *; do cwebp -q 100 -m 0 -af -sharp_yuv "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"; done`
```

#### Option 2 (Easier): using Git Bash

1. Download and install Git for Windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win);
2. Right click to the folder where the unoptimized images are in > select "Git Bash Here";
3. Run the following script (don't forget the backticks):

```
`for file in *; do cwebp -q 100 -m 0 -af -sharp_yuv "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"; done`
```

---

**To learn more about `cwebp` options, go to its documentation:** https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp.